# AJAX stop working on loading same site different PHP id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i have a [website](http://vrl.liblik.ee) that I'm doing for a school project. It's supposed to be like PasteBin. So on the right theres a different div (Uued koodid) that shows newest pastes. On click, they are supposed to show what they include using AJAX to refresh the left div. This only works for 4 times and then stops, but URL is still changing. After refresh it changes again and works again for 4 more times.

In main.js i have

```
...
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
...
$(".uuedKoodid").click(function () {
    $(".left-content").load(document.location.hash.substr(1));
});
...
```

EDIT:
Also other AJAX functions work. If I log in, I can switch between settings and profile perfectly but still cannot watch new codes

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout` with `0` as the timeout?\

Comment: My bad, it was old paste. I edit! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace right menu with new code (from ajax call) you don't attach click event again on `.uuedKoodid` items so they don't do anything. You need to attach event again or attach it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.uuedKoodid', function () {
  $(".left-content").load(document.location.hash.substr(1));
});
```

Edit:
As you noticed this will cause small problem. `onclick` event run before browser run standard link action. First you load ajax and then browser changes address. This way you are 1 action behind. Better solution than reading with delay (`setTimeout`) i think would be to read address directly from link:

```
$(document).on('click', '.uuedKoodid', function () {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $(".left-content").load(url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1));
});
```

Comment: Now it works partly. Ajax keeps on refreshing, but its behind 1 step.
When i click on 1st - 1st loads, click on 2nd - nothing, click on 3rd - 2nd loads, click on 4th - 3rd loads.

Comment: Adding the setTimeout to wait before getting the URL helped! Thank you